# Send websocket messages on demand, outside of callbacks?

Tags: python, websocket

I have the backend to a toy video game engine written in Python.  It's running on my server in its continuous game loop.  I want it to be able to send messages to web browser clients over websockets.

However, it looks to me like websockets are universally limited to sending information on callbacks alone.  I tried using the Autobahn websockets library for Python, but when the server is run, it runs in a blocking loop, so you can't even interact with it -- you can only define its behavior ahead of time in callbacks.

I just want to be able to instantiate a type of MyWebsocketNetwork, which will run its server in the background, and be able to call myWebsocketNetwork.sendToAll("my message") anywhere in my code to send my messages on demand.  NOT in callbacks, but on demand.  Again, I can't find a way to do this with Autobahn (or any other library) since they all run in blocking lops.

Is this in general not possible due to the nature of websockets?  Or is there some way I can send websocket messages to my clients on demand in Python (on demand = dynamically and conditionally based upon what happens in my game's loop).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand what you mean.  Callbacks *are* on-demand.  It sounds like you need to create your WebSocket in a separate thread.

Comment: This is specific to autobahn, but here's my problem: I create my client, in which I define how to behave onMessage, onConnect, etc.  I define my server the same way.  They each go in an asyncio loop, and then loop.run_forever().  So their behavior is only predefined--how do I, externally, say "I want to arbitrarily send this message to the server, not from within a callback, but from my external game engine which owns this client?"

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with autobahn, but just a thought in case it helps you... if you have the reference to the WebSocket outside of your asyncio loop, why can't you merely the-ws-reference.send("stuff to client")  ?